How to use il2cpp_xxx functions to get class and method information of ilruntime hot fix dll?
For Unity games, we can use il2cpp_domain_get， il2cpp_thread_attach，il2cpp_domain_get_assemblies... functions to get c# class and method information. But now most of the unity games use ilruntime to create a domain and load hot fix assembly into that domain. And il2cpp_domain_get will only return the default domain. Is there any way to use all these il2cpp functions to work on hot fix domain and dll?
